# Restart autonumbering in R officer package

Tags: r, officer

I am numbering tables and figures sequentially using

```r
run_autonum(seq_id = "fig", ...)
```

I would like to restart numbering within each section of the document.  I can't find anything in the User's Manual or Stack Overflow but a Microsoft website says:

> these can be restarted via the \r switch

I have no idea how to implement this within officer.  Does anyone have an idea?